# Logger to syslog with error_log fallback

Tags: php, unit-testing

Below is an implementation of a typical `Logger` interface that uses `syslog()` as the default means to store messages and falls back to `error_log()` if that does not work.  This is the first time I've used `syslog` and just want to ensure that my code is logical and there isn't something about `syslog` that I'm not aware of that could come back and bite me.  The code does work, messages are appearing in `syslog` as appropriate.

- [Project github repo](https://github.com/cspray/SprayFire)
- [Source code for Logger interface](https://github.com/cspray/SprayFire/blob/master/libs/SprayFire/Logger/Log.php)
- [Source code for extended class](https://github.com/cspray/SprayFire/blob/master/libs/SprayFire/Core/CoreObject.php)

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * @brief Holds a class that implements error logging to an OS or system logger.
 */

namespace SprayFire\Logger;

/**
 * @brief A SprayFire.Logger.Log implementation that will attempt to log a message
 * to syslog and as a fallback will log the message to whatever option is set in
 * the error_log php.ini directive.
 *
 * @uses SprayFire.Logger.Log
 * @uses SprayFire.Core.CoreObject
 */
class SystemLogger extends \SprayFire\Core\CoreObject implements \SprayFire\Logger\Log {

    /**
     * @brief A flag to tell if fallback should be used.
     *
     * @property $syslogOpened
     */
    protected $syslogOpened = false;

    /**
     * @param $syslogIdent
     */
    public function __construct($syslogIdent = 'SprayFire') {
        $this->syslogOpened = \openlog($syslogIdent, \LOG_NDELAY, \LOG_USER);
    }

    /**
     * @param $syslogSeverity The timestamp for the \a $message being logged
     * @param $message The message to be logged
     * @return true if the message was logged, false if not
     */
    public function log($syslogSeverity, $message) {
        $loggedtoSyslog = $this->logToSyslog($syslogSeverity, $message);
        if (!$loggedtoSyslog) {
            return $this->logToErrorLog($message);
        }
        return $loggedToSyslog;
    }

    /**
     * @param $syslogSeverity The severity of the syslog message to store
     * @param $message The message to store in syslog
     * @return true if the message was logged into syslog, false if it wasn't
     * @see http://www.php.net/syslog
     */
    protected function logToSyslog($syslogSeverity, $message) {
        if ($this->syslogOpened) {
            return \syslog($syslogSeverity, $message);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param $message The message to log with error_log
     * @return true if logged, false if not
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php
     */
    protected function logToErrorLog($message) {
        $message = \date('M-d-Y H:i:s') . ' := ' . $message;
        return \error_log($message);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Ensures that the syslog is properly closed if it was opened.
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        if ($this->syslogOpened) {
            \closelog();
        }
    }

}
```

One question that I would have is how to unit test this?  How would I disable `syslog` to ensure the fallback is called?  Or is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `SysLog` interface and a `SysLogImpl` implementation class.

```
public interface SysLog {
    public bool openlog(string $ident, int $option ,int $facility);
    public bool syslog (int $priority, string $message);
    public bool closelog (void);
}
```

`SysLogImpl` just delegate the calls to the `openlog`, `syslog` and `closelog` PHP functions.

```
public class SysLogImpl implements SysLog {
    public bool openlog(string $ident, int $option, int $facility) {
        return openlog($ident, $option, $facility);
    }

    public bool syslog(int $priority, string $message) {
        return syslog($priority, $message);
    }

    public bool closelog (void) {
        return closelog();
    }
}
```

It's important that this class should be just a thin facade without any logic since this class usually doesn't have any test or just has a few integration tests.

In production code pass a `SysLogImpl` instance to the constructor of your `SystemLogger` class and use this `SysLogImpl` instance instead of direct PHP calls.

In test code pass a mocked or a custom object which implements the `SysLog` interface to the `SystemLogger` class. The passed object should be able to store function calls and emulate responses (as mock objects do).

Maybe you'll need an `ErrorLog` interface and an `ErrorLogImpl` implementation class which logs with `error_log` PHP calls.

---

Another solution is a [Test-Specific Subclass](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html). You can extract out the `openlog` call from the constructor to a separate function and create a subclass of the `SystemLogger` which overrides this method and returns `false`.

---

A better and generic design would be creating a common `Logger` interface and a `SyslogLogger` and an `ErrorLogLogger` implementation classes. Both implements `Logger`. Then the `SystemLogger` class get one or more `Logger` instances and try calling their `open` functions and use that implementation whose `open` function returns `true` first.

If you use this the `SystemLogger` has only one responsibility: managing loggers, while `SyslogLogger` cares only about `syslog` and `ErrorLogLogger` cares only about `error_log` logging.

Comment: Ok, let's say that I have a common `Logger` interface.  Would it make sense for all `Loggers` to have an `openlog()` method?  What if the log isn't something that can really be opened?  Should it just return `true`?

Comment: Yes, just return `true`. It's totally fine, not all resource needs opening (nor closing).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I took your advice and looked at the interface for my `Logger`.  However, some concerns I have with the API drove me to [ask another question in regards to your answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/refactoring-logger-interface-to-open-and-close-logs).  If you have the time I would appreciate your feedback.